# Slow Access Append Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query, `A`, in my ms-access database that takes ~2 seconds to execute. `A` gives me six fields: `Field1`, `Field2`, ..., `Field6`.

I must append the results of `A` to a table, `T`.

I created a query, `B`, that selects columns from `A` and inserts them into table `T`. However, `B` takes more than 10 minutes to run... Why? and How do I speed-up `B`?

Here is the code for `B`:

```
INSERT INTO TrialRuns (Field1,Field2,...,Field6)
SELECT A.Field1,A.Field2,...,Field6
From A
```

Comment: Got any constraints on that table (primary key/unique constraint, validation rule/check constraint, validation rule) or a trigger or similar? Compacted the database recently? How many existing rows, how many being inserted?

Comment: No constraints/trigger/similar on the table. I've tried compacting the database (more than once). There are <20k existing records and I'm inserting 6.6k new ones. No calculations are done by `B`; it's simply taking the data that was computed by `A` and appending it to `T`.

Comment: I do have an AutoNumber primary key, every other field is unconstrained

Comment: Maybe it's simply that the calculations take a long time? How long does it take to insert to a new table e.g. `SELECT * INTO X FROM A;` ?

Comment: @onedaywhen I return to work on Tuesday; will try inserting into a new table at that time and follow up with the results.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

INSERT INTO TrialRuns
SELECT * FROM A;

Answer (score 0):

Try;

SELECT A.Field1,A.Field2,...,Field6
INTO TrialRuns
FROM A

Note that this may only work if you make sure that the TrialRuns table doesn't exist to begin with, so do a DROP TABLE TrialRun beforehand if it does exist.  This should take as long to run as the initial SELECT statement.